# How to find objects by date range in MongoDB using a different timezone than UTC?

Tags: spring, mongodb, datetime, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Since MongoDB stores date objects in UTC and my Spring application has a default timezone of `America/New_York`, how do I query the database by date range in a `America/New_York` timezone?

For example, each document in a collection has a `createdDate` in UTC, I want to query for documents that were created after midnight 11/20/2020 in `America/New_York` timezone, how do I do that in my Spring Data MongoDB application?

If I blindly find by midnight then the returned object will be 4-5 hours before midnight, which means 11/19/2020 (because UTC midnight is 4/5 hours ahead depending on months).

My Spring application stores date time in a Java `LocalDateTime` object. The date time in the database looks like this: `2020-10-28T03:40:49.132+00:00`

Comment: Look for $dateToString in mongo or try to use `ZonedDateTime`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `$dateFromString` in aggregation pipeline to project a flag and filter using the flag:

```
db.getCollection(<collection name>).aggregate([
    {
        $addFields : {
            largerThan : {
                $gte : [
                    "$createdDate",
                    { 
                        $dateFromString: {
                            dateString: "2020-11-20T00:00:00.000",
                            timezone: "America/New_York"
                        } 
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match : {
            largerThan : true
        }
    }
])
```

ref: [$dateFromString MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/)